# How to reshape a dataframe with added attributes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a Pandas DataFrame of stock closing prices from a list of tickers which I pulled from pandas_datareader.

```
tickers = ['FB', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'RSP']
stocks = web.DataReader(tickers,'yahoo',start_date,end_date)
stocks
```

Currently my DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

I tried to set the date and symbols as my index like so `stocks.set_index(['Date','Symbols]) but I get this error:

`KeyError: "None of ['Date', 'Symbols'] are in the columns"`

How do I reshape the DataFrame so my columns are in this order: Date, Symbols, Close

Comment: `Date` is already your index and `Symbols` is your columns. Do you want `stocks.stack()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from pandas_datareader import data

```
tickers = ['FB', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'RSP']
start_date,end_date = "2020-04-01", "2020-04-10"
stocks = data.DataReader(tickers,'yahoo',start_date,end_date)
stocks_close = stocks['Close']

s1 = stocks_close.stack(0) # multi-index pandas dataframe
s2 = s1.reset_index() # no index, flatted and repeated
```

s1 give :

```
Date        Symbols
2020-04-01  AAPL        240.910004
            AMZN       1907.699951
            FB          159.600006
            RSP          79.879997
2020-04-02  AAPL        244.929993
            AMZN       1918.829956
            FB          158.190002
            RSP          81.139999
2020-04-03  AAPL        241.410004
            AMZN       1906.589966
            FB          154.179993
            RSP          79.830002
2020-04-06  AAPL        262.470001
            AMZN       1997.589966
            FB          165.550003
            RSP          85.870003
2020-04-07  AAPL        259.429993
            AMZN       2011.599976
            FB          168.830002
            RSP          86.559998
2020-04-08  AAPL        266.070007
            AMZN       2043.000000
            FB          174.279999
            RSP          90.139999
2020-04-09  AAPL        267.989990
            AMZN       2042.760010
            FB          175.190002
            RSP          92.220001
```

s2 :

```
         Date Symbols            0
0  2020-04-01    AAPL   240.910004
1  2020-04-01    AMZN  1907.699951
2  2020-04-01      FB   159.600006
3  2020-04-01     RSP    79.879997
4  2020-04-02    AAPL   244.929993
5  2020-04-02    AMZN  1918.829956
6  2020-04-02      FB   158.190002
7  2020-04-02     RSP    81.139999
8  2020-04-03    AAPL   241.410004
9  2020-04-03    AMZN  1906.589966
10 2020-04-03      FB   154.179993
11 2020-04-03     RSP    79.830002
12 2020-04-06    AAPL   262.470001
13 2020-04-06    AMZN  1997.589966
14 2020-04-06      FB   165.550003
15 2020-04-06     RSP    85.870003
16 2020-04-07    AAPL   259.429993
17 2020-04-07    AMZN  2011.599976
18 2020-04-07      FB   168.830002
19 2020-04-07     RSP    86.559998
20 2020-04-08    AAPL   266.070007
21 2020-04-08    AMZN  2043.000000
22 2020-04-08      FB   174.279999
23 2020-04-08     RSP    90.139999
24 2020-04-09    AAPL   267.989990
25 2020-04-09    AMZN  2042.760010
26 2020-04-09      FB   175.190002
27 2020-04-09     RSP    92.220001
```

if u want rename the third column of s2:

```
s2.columns = ['Dates', 'Symbols', 'Close']
```